# MySQL on foreign key duplication insert ignore

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get insertion ignored on duplication of `image_id`:

```
INSERT INTO `images`(item_id, image_id) VALUES ("2", "23") // ignore when item_id 2 already have a record with image _id 23

images
------

item_id      image_id
-------      --------
   1            22
   1            23
   1            55
   2            23
   2            46
   2            57
   3            46
```

If i will try to add image_id 23 for item_id 2, it won't be inserted, but for item_id 3 it will.

Comment: If this is for the purpose of line items of an invoice then it's better to have another column saying Quantity. Because in that way you won't need to add two lines for the same line item (image_id) but update the quantity to be 2.

Comment: Each Item_id should have only one line for specific image_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique index on item_id and image_id.

```
ALTER TABLE `images` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `my_image_index` (`item_id`, `image_id`)
```